# Get response from CompletableFuture

Tags: java, completable-future

I'm trying to add `Async` to my fetch operation from the db. However, I'm stuck at trying to get the response from `CompletableFuture.allOf()`. Join return a 'void. Instead how can I return a `List<QuestionResponseData>` as mentioned in the code.  Below is my code

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, path = "/questionsByAssessmentIdAndQuestionNumber")
    public List<QuestionResponseData> getQuestionsByIdAndLimit(@RequestBody QuestionOptionRequest questionOptionRequest) {
        String assessmentId = questionOptionRequest.getAssessmentId();
        QuestionOptionRequest request = QuestionOptionRequest.builder().assessmentId(questionOptionRequest.getAssessmentId()).startingQuestion(1).build();
        CompletableFuture<List<QuestionResponseData>> questions = questionService.getQuestions(request);
        QuestionOptionRequest request1 = QuestionOptionRequest.builder().assessmentId(assessmentId).startingQuestion(26).build();
        CompletableFuture<List<QuestionResponseData>> questions1 = questionService.getQuestions(request1);
        QuestionOptionRequest request2 = QuestionOptionRequest.builder().assessmentId(assessmentId).startingQuestion(51).build();
        CompletableFuture<List<QuestionResponseData>> questions2 = questionService.getQuestions(request2);
        QuestionOptionRequest request3 = QuestionOptionRequest.builder().assessmentId(assessmentId).startingQuestion(76).build();
        CompletableFuture<List<QuestionResponseData>> questions3 = questionService.getQuestions(request3);

        CompletableFuture.allOf(questions, questions1, questions2, questions3).join();

        //return questionService.getQuestions(questionOptionRequest);
    }
```

Comment: [`CompletableFuture::allOf` returns a `CompletableFuture<Void>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf(java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...)). You would have to create the resultlist manually.

Comment: You have 4 separate result lists so presumably you need to collate them into one list.  Consider adding a 'thenAccept' stage to each individual future that moves its result to the combined list, and then wait for allOf those to complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 CompletableFuture<List<QuestionResponseData>> futures = new CompletableFuture[]{request, request1, request2, request3};

 List<QuestionResponseData> result =
    CompletableFuture.allOf(futures)
            .thenApply(_void -> Arrays.stream(futures).map(CompletableFuture::join).flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .join();
```

Notice that calling `CompletableFuture::join` does not actually block, the blocking has already happened in `CompletableFuture::allOf`